# Why are frames skipped on render? Orange line while viewing in 3d view

Tags: rendering, animation, error

I am making an animation.

When I render my animation, there are a couple of empty frames in the exported video.

These don't seem to be a render error, however.

When I view the animation in 3d view, the frames in question don't show my object, but a vertical orange line instead. For example, frame 39 shows my object in its frame 39 state, and frame 41 shows my object in its frame 41 state. And frame 40 shows me this:

[image]

No object, just this orange line, which is otherwise not visible.

Why is this? What does the line represent? How can I fix my animation to not have this error?

Comment: Please, share .Blend file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the file itself as it is part of a confidential work project.

Comment: Well, can you post screenshots of modifier stack, constraints or anything that contributes in actual animation of this object?

Comment: I'm using keyframes to rotate, scale and mirror the object, which has soft body physics applied. That is all that constitutes the animation. I'm quite new to Blender so unfortunately I don't know where to screenshot the exact parameters. Would that help though?

Comment: This orange line is outliner for your object and it looks like line, because object is scaled to zero on every axis except Z. It is hard to tell, what is going on without knowing what this object was doing on previous frames or how does it interact with others. Also you don't need to share whole scene, just this object, even without materials.